# Strange Behavior in Python's Remove Function

Tags: python, loops, behavior

Can anyone explain to me exactly why this Python script produces this output?

```
>>> a = range(0,50)  
>>> for x in a:  
...     a.remove(x)  
...   
>>> a  
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39]
```

This seems strange to me, because the script only removes every second entry. I would think that the loop would iteratively remove all the items in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What

```
for x in a:
```

Really does is that it uses an internal counter, so it will return a[0], a[1], a[2]...

What happens with your code is that removing an item changes the position where the loop index should point, so:

First loop, `index == 0`, you remove `a[0]`, which is 0. Second loop, index is 1, but now, a is [1..49], and `a[1]` is 2.

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = range(0,50)  
>>> for x in a[:]:
...     a.remove(x)  
...   
>>> a  
[]
```

Make a copy of the list (`a[:]`) so you are not modifying it while iterating through it.